# dummy coding categories in two different variables that are identical

Tags: logistic, categorical-encoding

I have a dataset predicting disease or not from several different variables. Two of the variables denote the status of pathological lymph nodes - one pertaining to consistency (three levels A, B and not present) and the other to size in mm (0-10, 10-20, 20+ and not present). The problem arises when the lymph node is not present and the results are all over the place for the not_present category in both consistency and size - presumably do to collinearity. Any good suggestions as to how I can recode this - I´d rather not just code them as missing since the observations are valuable for the other variables?